# Question about a Power Series problem

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

Pardon me if this is a stupid question, but this is my first time doing Power Series. The question is:

*Find the radius of convergence and interval of convergence for the series.*

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n+1}}{4n!} $$

Here what I tried:
[image: Work]

This gives me a radius of convergence of 0, which certainly cannot be right. Can someone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: No, the outcome of the Ratio test is zero. This means that the interval of convergence is the real number line (the series converges for any chosen $x$) so we are talking about a very BIG radius.....